# How to get the run id and put it into a variable in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I want to get the run_id of the executed DAG and treat it as a variable of the DAG itself.
Is there a function for this?

```
with DAG(
    dag_id='question',
    ...
) as dag:
    
    question = PythonOperator(
        task_id='question_python',
        python_callable=question_python,
        op_kwargs={run_id:#here },
    )
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no need to use `op_kwargs` here. `run_id` is a [macro](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html#templates-reference) provided by Airflow thus it's available in the context of the python callable:

```
def question_python(run_id, **context):
    # your function code
```

or

```
def question_python(**context):
    run_id = context[run_id]
    # your function code
```

If you are using Airflow < 2.0:
You will need also to add `provide_context=True` to your `PythonOperator`